# Set boolean (single on/off checkbox) value while creating a user

Tags: entities, users

I am creating a user programmatically and there is a boolean field (single on/off checkbox) being used as a terms of use inside the users profile.

How do I set the value of it when creating a user object? I need it to be checked or 1.

```
$new_user = array(
                'name' => $username,
                'mail' => $email,
                //'pass' => $pass,
                'signature_format' => 'full_html',
                'status' => 1,
                'access' => 0,
                'timezone' => 'America/New_York',
                'init' => $email,
                'field_user_account_terms' => array(
                    'attributes' => array(
                        'checked' => 'checked',
                    ),
                ),
              );

$account = user_save(NULL, $new_user);
```

i've also tried

```
                    'field_user_account_terms' => array(
                    'und' => array(
                        0 => array(
                            'value' =>  1,
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
```

I've also tried setting the default value and a bunch of other syntax. Nothing seems to be working for me.

**is this even possible? What is the correct syntax for setting the value of a checkbox, to be saved in a users profile?**

Comment: Are you sure "1" is the checkbox key? You'll need to use the field value key there, as per your second solution above.

Comment: @DavidThomas i'm not sure I just assumed 0 or 1 because it's boolean. or checked because it's a checkbox. I can't find a working solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The help message for this field says: **If left empty, "1" will be used** and **if left empty, "0" will be used**. So I left this field blank and assumed you could programmatically set the value while creating a user. This doesn't work at all for me.

[image]

You actually have to explicitly define the *On* and *Off* values in order to be able to set them while creating a user.

[image]

Then you can set the value in the user object.

```
'field_user_account_terms' => array(
                'und' => array(
                    0 => array(
                        'value' =>  1,
                    ),
                ),
            ),
```